# Position: fixed and javascript isnt working

Tags: javascript

I have a weird question. I have a color palette in my chat room and I don't understand when I am applying `position:fixed` the JavaScript doesn't work and if I remove the `position:fixed` it works.

Is this something that happens or should I attempt to try another way? I don't know how to overlay the color palette over the chat dialog without using position fixed an margins to place the content where I want it.

Any input?

I know that there is a lot of code but I just want you to have a idea when you look at it. It could be me that messed something up.

The error has to be on this page or the css

index.php

```
<div id="colorpickerB" style='display:none;'>
  <div id="colorpicker">
    <img src="palette.png" id="palette" alt="Color Palette" border="1"/>
    <br />
    <input id="color" type="hidden" readonly="true" value="#000000" />
  </div>    
</div>
<table id="content">
  <tr id="chat-top">
    <td>
      <div id="scroll">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="chat-btm">
    <td colspan="2">
      <div id="items">
        <input type="text" class="" id="messageBox" placeholder="Enter your message here" maxlength="2000" size="30" />
      </div>
      <div id="color">
        <button type="button" id="sampleText" class="chat-btn" onclick="toggleElement('colorpickerB');">
          Color
        </button>
      </div>          
      <input type="hidden" class="" id="userName" value="<?php echo $log_username; ?>" maxlength="20"/>
      <input type="button" class="chat-btn" value="Send" id="send" />
      <?php
      if ($user_ok === true) {
          if (($log_userlevel == '7') || ($log_userlevel == '8')) {
            echo '<input type="button" class="chat-btn" value="Delete All" id="delete" />';
          }
        }
      ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
   #colorpicker {
   margin: 5px 0px 0px 6px;
   }
   #colorpickerB{
   position: fixed;
   margin: 90px 0 0px 461px;
   border: solid 1px black;
   width: 290px;
   height: 273px;
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 2000;
   }
```

Comment: You say javascript isn't working.   There is no javascript in the code you posted.   And "isn't working" is very little information.   Please create a jsFiddle that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: couldn't even get the toggle function to work. I figure it out thanks anyways